# Opposite to jQuery's .Closest (Top/Far-Most?)

Tags: jquery, dom, parent, closest

I have a code with lots of submenus that share the same class name.

Here's a structure:

```
.menu
  .sub-menu
  .sub-menu
    .sub-menu
    .sub-menu
  .sub-menu
    .sub-menu
      .elem
      .elem
  .sub-menu
```

Note that `.sub-menu` may be infinite levels deep.

So how do I achieve this: when `.elem` is clicked, I want to travers the DOM upwards until the top-most `.sub-menu` is reached and apply a style to it. I am aware of `.closest()` and `.parent()` and `.find()`, but I have no idea if jQuery has such feature such as `.topMost(selector)`?

The only way I can think of is maybe running a loop and going through `.closest('.sub-menu')` of the new element until its length is zero (there are no more parents with this class, so it must be the top-most). However, I think there should be a more practical approach to this.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming by 'opposite of closest' you want the 'furthest' *parent* element, you can use `parents().last()`, like this:

```
$('.elem').on('click', e => {
  var $topSubMenu = $(e.target).parents('.sub-menu').last();
});
```

Note, you want the last element in the array as jQuery traverses up the DOM, so the top-level item will the final one in the collection.

If instead you mean that you want the 'closest' *child* element, then you can use `find('.submenu').first()`, like this:

```
$('.elem').on('click', e => {
  var $topSubMenu = $(e.target).find('.submenu').first();
});
```

You could potentially use `children('.submenu')` here instead of `find()` - it depends how many levels down the DOM tree you need to traverse.

Answer (score 33):

The question is slightly misleading as .`closest`() could be misinterpreted. Actually it means search up the tree until the first match is found. So the opposite is search down the tree until a match is found and that method is `first().`

To find *all* descendants one might use `find()`. The opposite of `find()` is `parents()`.

**closest()** (all levels)
*For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

**first()** (all levels)
*Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set*

**parents()** (all levels)
*Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.*

**parent()** (next level only)
*Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.*

**find()** (all levels) Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Comment: Feel free to edit the title to a more suitable one if you think it will clarify the purpose of the question for future readers.

Comment: Im cool with it. Its what i googled. Just posted it for future reference :)

Comment: This is incorrect with regard to find() being the opposite of closest(). find() will find all elements in the tree. So the opposite of closest(), searching down, would be find().first().

Comment: Cool! Took away the down vote and up voted instead. This should be helpful to others coming upon this post.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a JavaScript-only solution, based on the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill) for `closest()`.

```
function furthest(s) {
    var el = this.parentElement || this.parentNode;
    var anc = null;

    while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1) {
        if (el.matches(s)) anc = el;
        el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
    }
    return anc;
}
```

Comment: I added element as a parameter because this.parentElement doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` could actually be used here, by passing a selector that restricts the matched elements to those which are direct descendants of `.menu`:

```js
$('.elem').click(function() {
    let $topSubMenu = $(this).closest('.menu > .sub-menu');
});
```