# Better way to nest javascript closest (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, nested, closest

I use **vanilla javascript**, no jQuery.

In my code I have something that looks like this:

```
item.closest('ul').closest('li').closest('ul').classList.add('active');
```

While it works, it does not look that nice. I repeat `closest` three times.

Is it possible to so something smarter in this case?

Comment: So `.closest()` is your own definition? I'll go with adding `class` so that it's not like `.parentNode.parentNode`!

Comment: You're using jQuery, are'nt you?

Comment: can you add your html ?

Comment: If the markup is what I would expect (without seeing it), you can at least remove the middle `.closest("li")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opposite to jQuery's .Closest (Top/Far-Most?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787618/opposite-to-jquerys-closest-top-far-most)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot make it shorter without writing a function that builds the chain. Since you want to select the parent, you'd need the [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) css selector to make it shorter (`item.closest('ul:has(li ul)')`) but it is not supported by all browsers

Comment: @Ebatsin I don't use jQuery so it does not work.

Comment: Can't you add a class to the target `ul` and select it with `closest`? Something like this: `item.closest('ul.my-ul').classList.add('active')`.

Comment: @JensTörnell I never talked about using jQuery, the [has selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) is a standard css selector level 4. It is just not usable now because of browser support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way of making this shorter.

You can:

1. Add a class to the element you are trying to select. That would make your selector look like this :
   `item.closest('ul.myClass').classlist.add('active')`
2. Create a function that wraps the `closest` chain creation :

   ```
   function closestChain(item) {
       return Array.from(arguments).reduce((acc, val) => {
           return acc.closest(val);
       });
   }

   closestChain(item, 'ul', 'li', 'ul').classlist.add('active');
   ```
3. Or you can wait for the [has CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) to be available